# Login HTML - PHP y SH

Tags: php, html, bash, sh

Mi problema es que quiero que cuando se inserte por ejemplo el usuario "pepito" y se le de a enviar en el formulario se envíe al PHP, se guarde en una variable, la cuál se pasará al script.sh para que se cree un archivo con el nombre del usuario que se inserto. Hice el código pero no me funciona, se agradece la ayuda. Un saludo.

Formulario HTML **`index.html`**:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formulario" method="post" action="registro.php">
 <p>Usuario: <input type="text" name="usuario"></p>
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Archivo **`registro.php`**:

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['usuario'];
shell_exec("sh script.sh $username");
echo $username;
?>
```

Archivo **`script.sh`**:

```
#!/bin/bash
usuario=$1
touch /home/usuario/Escritorio/$usuario
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente el código está bien. Quizás deberías revisar los permisos del usuario que se usa en php para ejecutar ese comando, la ruta del script, etc. Para eso haz lo siguiente:

En el fichero registro.php modifica la línea 3 para dejarla así:

```
var_dump(shell_exec("sh script.sh $username"));
```

Al menos con eso verás qué le devuelve sh a PHP explicando porqué no lo ejecuta.

Comment: me devuelve, **NULL pepito**

Comment: Prueba a poner lo siguiente, para redireccionar los errores (stderr) a la salida (stdout)
var_dump(shell_exec("sh script.sh $username 2>&1"));

Comment: string(73) "touch: cannot touch '/home/usuario/Escritorio/pepito': Permission denied "

Comment: Muy bien, pues ahí lo tienes. Apache, o cualquiera que sea el servidor http que estes usando está bajo su propio usuario el cual no tiene permisos para esa ruta. Deberás dar los permisos a ese directorio que sean necesarios para que el servidor web pueda escribir en él (no vayas a lo loco con 777, no es la solución)